# Heavily overlapping data

Tags: r, prediction

I have the data:

```
tibble(r) %>% 
  head()
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  r$rating $sympathy
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 5            11.5 
2 5            12.7 
3 5            12.0 
4 3.5           8.33
5 5            10.6 
6 5            11.2
```

With `>1e05` observations.

I am looking for an idea how to predict the `rating` by some abstract `sympathy` parameter.

I tried to apply the random forest classifier. With the `randomForest` library, I achieved `RMSE > 1.04`. I am looking for the method to decrease `RMSE` to value about `0.8`.

[image: i]

```
r %>% 
  group_by(rating) %>% 
  summarise_each(list(mean = mean, sd = sd, error = std.error)) %>%
  mutate(si = mean - 1.96 * sd, se = mean + 1.96 * sd)
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   rating  mean    sd    error    si    se
   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 0.5     7.93  1.60 0.00546   4.80  11.1
 2 1       8.23  1.54 0.00262   5.21  11.2
 3 1.5     8.39  1.43 0.00439   5.58  11.2
 4 2       8.76  1.45 0.00172   5.92  11.6
 5 2.5     8.88  1.38 0.00239   6.18  11.6
 6 3       9.34  1.42 0.000973  6.56  12.1
 7 3.5     9.60  1.39 0.00156   6.88  12.3
 8 4       9.98  1.45 0.000899  7.15  12.8
 9 4.5    10.3   1.47 0.00202   7.46  13.2
10 5      10.5   1.55 0.00132   7.50  13.6
```

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Could you explain the circumstances?  At the moment all we have to go on is a bunch of histograms, which could be interpreted in very many ways.  What do they have to do with a "rating," what do the separate histograms mean, and how might they be related?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the comment! I added some details to the question.